# Laravel PHP: Selected Category total changes/resets to '0' when using additional pagination pages

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a Laravel PHP application that allows the user to select a category from a drop down box and after the user makes their selection, the application then retrieves the results via a **Form Submission** by matching on the selected category.  I am currently paginating the number of results to 10 per page.  After results are retrieved, there are 2 totals that are displayed

1) The total number of results from all categories. 
2) The number of results from the selected category.

Once the form is submitted, the above totals are displayed correctly but only for the first page of results.  The problem occurs when viewing additional pages of results, for example if there are **15 total records** and **Category1** from the drop down box contains **12 records**, when the user selects this category and then submits the form, the following output will be displayed:

**Page 1**

Total Records: 15
Category Results: 12

Now when using the Laravel pagination links, created in the view using

```
{{ $allpics->appends(array('category' => $category))->links()}}
```

If the user navigates to Page 2, the following output is displayed:

**Page 2**

Total Records: 15
Category Results: 0

I have tried several approaches to fixing this problem by using the '**$_GET[]**' command with '**$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']**' to determine if both a '**page**' and '**category**' variable are appended when navigating to additional pages of results so that the number of Category results can then be queried again based on the selected category within the URL itself.  I still cannot get the number of category results to remain at the correct number when navigating to additional pages of results.

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $vdo = Video::query();
    $pic = Picture::query();

    if($category = Input::get('category')){
        $vdo->where('category', $category);
        $pic->where('category', $category);

        /* Old code */

        // $urlcategory = $_GET['category'];

        $urlcategory = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        $url_cat_page = parse_str($urlcategory);
        $url_page = $category;

        $totalCatVids = $vdo->where('category', $category);
        $totalCatPics = $pic->where('category', $category);

        $allvids = $vdo->paginate(10);
        $allpics = $pic->paginate(10);

        $totalVideos =   Video::all();
        $totalPictures = Picture::all();

        $data = compact('allvids','allpics', 'totalCatVids', 'totalCatPics', 'totalVideos', 'totalPictures', 'url_page');
        $data['category'] = Input::get('category');
        $this->layout->content = \View::make('home.picsvids.pics_vids_overview', $data);
    }

    else if (isset($_GET['category']) && $_GET['category'] == $category)
        {

            $vdo->where('category', $category);
            $pic->where('category', $category);

            $totalCatVids = $vdo->where('category', $category);
            $totalCatPics = $pic->where('category', $category);

            $allvids = $vdo->paginate(10);
            $allpics = $pic->paginate(10);

            $totalVideos =   Video::all();
            $totalPictures = Picture::all();

            $data = compact('allvids','allpics', 'totalCatVids', 'totalCatPics', 'totalVideos', 'totalPictures', 'url_page');
            $data['category'] = Input::get('category');

            $this->layout->content = \View::make('home.picsvids.pics_vids_overview', $data);
        }
        else
        {
        $urlcategory = '';

        $url_page = $category;              

        $totalCatVids = Video::all();
        $totalCatPics = Picture::all();                 

        $allvids = $vdo->paginate(10);
        $allpics = $pic->paginate(10);

        $totalVideos =   Video::all();
        $totalPictures = Picture::all();

        $data = compact('allvids','allpics', 'totalCatVids', 'totalCatPics', 'totalVideos', 'totalPictures', 'url_page');
        $data['category'] = Input::get('category');

        $this->layout->content = \View::make('home.picsvids.pics_vids_overview', $data);

        }
}
```

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem for awhile now and I'm not sure why the category total changes to **'0'** for additional pages of pagination instead of remaining at the correct category number, in this case **'12'** even after creating conditions based on the URL being appended with the selected category name.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: in the first if, you are assigning a value to category instead of comparing values. // you could save the value of category in session

Comment: @chepe263 Saving the value of category in a session did the trick!  I'm going to edit my answer above with your solution.  Thank you so much!

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a lot of repetition in your code, something like this might be easier to follow and should solve the category issue. Can't test it though, obvs

```
public function index()
{
    $totalVideos = Video::count();
    $totalPictures = Picture::count();

    $vdo = Video::query();
    $pic = Picture::query();

    if ($category = Input::get('category')) {
        $vdo->where('category', $category);
        $pic->where('category', $category);

        $totalCatPics = Picture::where('category', $category)->count();
        $totalCatVids = Video::where('category', $category)->count();

    } else {
        $totalCatPics = $totalPictures;
        $totalCatVids = $totalVideos;
    }

    $allvids = $vdo->paginate(10);
    $allpics = $pic->paginate(10);

    $data = compact('allvids','allpics', 'totalCatVids', 'totalCatPics', 'totalVideos', 'totalPictures', 'url_page');
    $data['category'] = $category;
    $this->layout->content = \View::make('home.picsvids.pics_vids_overview', $data);
}
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly and its very neat too!  Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

By using the solution provided by @chepe263, I modified my controller and view so now the category totals are no longer reset to 0 when navigating to additional pages of results via pagination.

**Controller:**

```
$totalCatPics = $pic->where('category', $category);

$_SESSION['totalcatpics'] = $totalCatPics->count();
```

**View:**

```
<b>Category Results: {{ $_SESSION['totalcatpics'] }}</b><br>
```

Hope this solution helps anybody else that runs into a similar problem!